# Colour separate groups of points by third variable

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have several separate lists of x and y variables e.g.:

```
x1=[1,2,3], y1=[1,2,3],
x2=[1,2,3], y2=[4,5,6]
x3=[1,2,3], y3=[7,8,9]
```

I also have a separate third variable, a value respective for each set of data: e.g. `var=[10,20,30]`.

I wish to plot the separate groups of points, and colour each **group** according to the third variable, from cold to hot depending on the value in var. I.e. the entire of dataset of x1,y1 will be the same colour and that will be according to the value 10.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am confused by: "I also have a separate third variable..." Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Are you looking for `scatter` or `groupby`?

Comment: @tcaswell: Upon looking at his question further, I think he wants each pair of xn and yn to have a uniform color, scatter changes all the colors slightly. So I don't think he wants scatter.

Comment: @anon The third variable I mean is something like temperature-so each set of x,y values was taken at a certain temp and I want to colour code them by that.

Comment: I do want each pair of xn,yn to have a uniform colour, with x1,y1 coloured according to the value var[0], x2,y2 coloured according to the value var[1] etc. What @anon has answered below is close to what I want. I was thinking scatter.. unless groupby is a better option though I'm unsure what that does!

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for the following as you have 3d points.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1=[1,2,3]; y1=[3,2,3]
x2=[-1,-2,-3]; y2=[4,5,6]
x3=[0,0,0]; y3=[7,8,9]

zS = [10, 20, 100]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Define the color map
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')

# Iterate through points and plot
for x, y, z in zip([x1, x2, x3], [y1, y2, y3], zS):
    ax.scatter(x[0], x[1], x[2], s=50,
               c=z, cmap=cm, vmin=0, vmax=100)

    ax.scatter(y[0], y[1], y[2], s=50, 
               c=z, cmap=cm, vmin=0, vmax=100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

This is a rather long winded way of doing it and it could be improved but I wanted to stick as close to the data that you had given.

If you end up plotting a large number of points in this manner I would suggest passing them all as arrays (inclusing the size) rather than looping over each point. This will speed it up quite a bit but is easier to digest at first I think.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
for i in range(3, 10, 3):
    color = (((i - 1) / 9.), 0.0, 1-((i - 1) / 9.)) #Generate a color for the points, blue to red.
    j = list(range(1, 3+1)) # Generate your data set.
    k = list(range(i-2, i+1))
    plt.plot(j,k, 'ro', c=color) # Plot each one
plt.axis([-1,4,-1,10])
plt.show() #Finally show it.
```

This produces:

[image]